# how to send automatically money back to customer by canceling the order

Tags: php, paypal

i have the following scenario.

- The customer rent something for 2 weeks (starting in 4 weeks) over my website and pays directly with paypal (let's say 100,00€)
- I block the period of the rented object, so that nobody else can rent this object for this period.
- 2 days before the customers period starts, he wants to cancel.

my conditions says, that he has to pay 50% of the complete order because he is not in the free to cancel period. (So let's say 50,00€)

So the user should be able to login to his customer account and cancel the order by clicking a button.

Now my Problem:

I want that the payment (In this case 50,00€) gets automatically done by my programm.
So that no real person needs to login to my paypal account and has to do the 50,00€ payment manually.

Is there any way to do that with the paypal api?

Comment: Why don't you read their documentation or simply ask them?

Comment: ofcause I'm reading the documentation. But until now I couldnt find the right way / the right function. So I clicked on "Support" on the paypal developer site. And from this site, I came to stackoverflow, because Paypal use it as forum.